# Jquery Ajax load() === pjax.reload()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pjax

How can I do the same as doing pjax reload method just on jQuery ajax?
In my app logic I update some data by php and need reload my view with the newest data. I need reload some container by ajax. How I can do this in ajax like pjax.reload()?

If I do this:

```
var url  = window.location.href;
$( "#ajax-comments-container" ).load( url + " #ajax-comments-container > *", function() {

//some code                               

} );
```

It is relevant to pjax.reload('#ajax-comments-container'); ?

Comment: Show how u try use jQuery.ajax()? Because of your question don't understand this(

Comment: var url  = window.location.href; $( "#ajax-comments-container" ).load( url + " #ajax-comments-container > *",function() {});